# Angular2-fullcalendar is not an NgModule. Unexpected directive CalendarComponent

Tags: fullcalendar

On latest versions of Angular-cli the angular2-fuullcalendar is not working due:

"ERROR in CalendarComponent is not an NgModule"

In the browser I find the follow message:
"Error: Unexpected directive 'CalendarComponent'"

I've experienced the same error on my own libraries. Please check the follow post and the solution:

[ERROR in ** is not an NgModule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673916/error-in-is-not-an-ngmodule/42109940#42109940)